# It has been used correctly this phrase in this paragraph?

Tags: writing-style, style-manuals

I am wondering whether the following paragraph is clear. I am particularly concerned about the last phrase (emphasized).

> Joined work with local authorities to find alternatives to confront
> climatic emergencies, such as the severe drought that affected the
> biodiversity and economy of the region of Nualt in 2015.Seven maps and
> two studies that my team and I developed, *were used to identify key
> areas where to invest resources in order to achieve the highest
> positive environmental impact*.

Comment: It sounds like your team developed maps and studies that others used?

Comment: Pepo, the correct way to say this is: I am wondering whether the following paragraph is clear. And: Has this phrase been used correctly in this paragraph. English uses: Subject Verb Object Question: Auxiliary verb + subject + main verb.

Comment: The comma is unneeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular part of the identified sentence that seems troublesome to me is "to identify key areas where to ...". I think that a better construction is "to identify key areas ***in which*** to invest ...".

Additionally, I think that the opening of the sentence is strange, but perhaps you have not reproduced the entire sentence!? "Joined work" omits the subject of the verb. Who joined work? It should probably say "My team joined with local authorities..." or "My team worked jointly with local authorities ..."

Comment: user02814, This paragraph comes from my CV, it was one of my duties. Therefore, I used "Joined" as a synonym of cooperative work, which is intended to point out that I worked with the local authorities. I intended to use "joined" as an infinitive verb. I am not sure if I can use "My team joined with local authorities..." at the beginning because it is not an infinitive verb, and I do not if it is correct to indicate a duty in your cv.

Comment: If the structure is that of a series of dot-pointed CV entries, then you probably want "DOT Joint work with local authorities ..." not "Joined". An alternative might be "Jointly conducted work with ...". In either case, the words (joined, jointly" serve as an adjectival description of the kind of work. You might argue that "Joined" also serves the same function. All I can say is that it doesn't sound right to me!

Comment: user02814, I rewrite the paragraph, please let me know your thoughts:  -Jointly conducted work with local authorities to find alternatives to confront climatic emergencies, such as the severe drought that affected the biodiversity and economy of the region of Nualt in 2015.Seven maps and two studies that my team and I developed, were used to identify key ecosystems where to invest resources in order to achieve the best possible environmental scenario.

Comment: The first sentence of the rewrite sounds fine. The second sentence has one minor problem and one more significant problem. Minor: the comma after "developed" should be deleted. More significant: As I remarked in my main answer, "key ecosystems where to invest ..." is a poor construction. It should, in my opinion, be "key ecosystems in which to invest ..."

Comment: If you think the answer I gave is correct, you can upvote it, mark it as correct, or do both those things.